# Is there an API call for the service of a host? (Check MK version1.6.0p3) IE. "Services of Host xxx-xxx-xxx"

Tags: python, json, api, curl, check-mk

I would like to know if I can call a check_mk API endpoint that will retrieve the same information displayed under the  "Services of Host xxx-xxx-xxx" section where it displays system level metrics ie. "Check_MK, CPU load, Disk IO SUMMARY, Mount options of /data...etc"but into json or python format so that I can input this data into Influxdb/Grafana.

Im following 10.2 on https://checkmk.com/cms_web_api_references.html and I ran the below an got an error but according to the docs this SLA should be available being that im on 1.6.0p3

```
 curl "http://host/master/check_mk/webapi.py?action=get_sla&_username=user&_secret=***********" -d "request={'query': [[['my_sla_id1'],['d0'],[['host', 'CPU load']]]}"
{"result": "Check_MK exception: Unknown API action get_sla", "result_code": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might be a helpful alternative, have you checked this out?: https://github.com/tribe29/grafana-checkmk-datasource

Comment: You can flesh it out as an answer after getting clarifications from OP to know that the provided solution works. As it stands this is better as a comment.